# If a non-linear map preserves inner product, does it necessarily preserve distance?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products, isometry

Let $(S, \langle\, , \rangle)$ be a prehilbertian space.

I know that if a map $f: S \rightarrow S$ preserves norm but is not linear then it need not preserve metric. For instance, consider $f : (r\cos (\theta ), r\sin (\theta )) \mapsto$ $(r\cos (r\theta ), r\sin (r\theta )) $. We have $d(f(0,1),f(0,2))=||f(0,1)-f(0,2)||=||(0,1)-f(0,2)|| > 1=d((0,1),(0,2))$

Now I'm trying to find a counterexample for a map that preserves inner-product but, as above, doesn't preserve metric, but I've got a feeling this doesn't exist, am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the inner product space is real. (One can do the same computation for a complex inner product space.)
Note that
$$
(f(x),f(y))=(x,y),\quad\forall x,y\in S
$$
implies that
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\|^2=(f(x)-f(y),f(x)-f(y))=(x,x)+(y,y)-2(x,y)=\|x-y\|^2.
$$
and thus the distance must be preserved.

Comment: @JamesWell: Hopefully I have corrected my previous silly argument. Please check my new answer.

Comment: I made that silly mistake too, it's a well-hidden trap ! But this seems to work fine, thx !